# Backbone Response on Sync

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

First of all my knowledge of Backbone is very limited, and currently, I'm trying to add an implementation into some code I didn't create.

My problem is as follows:

I have a collection which is being rendered on click of a button. Now, we are setting some permissions on the website, so that sometimes the response I will get is a 401.

I'm currently able to get the response, the problem is that I don't know how to attach it to the sync event so that if I get a 401 when I call the API, it shouldn't render anything.

I would think looking at the code would help clarify my problem:

```
this.addressBook = new (Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: url,
        model: Backbone.Model.extend({
            idAttribute: 'ID'
        }),

        parse: function(data) {

            return data;
        }
}))();

    this.addressBook.on('sync', this.renderAddresses, this);
    this.addressBook.fetch();
```

So I found a few ways to get the status code from fetch, but in this particular case, I need to get the status code before the sync event calls this.renderAddress, and given the status of the response, go ahead and render my view or simply display a message stating that access is denied.

Sorry if I'm not clear enough.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the salient part of the backbone documentation:

> Whenever a model or collection begins a sync with the server, a "request" event is emitted. If the request completes successfully you'll get a "sync" event, and an "error" event if not.

This means that the `sync` event shouldn't fire if you get a 401, rather the `error` event should be triggered.

You can test this in your code by listening to all the different events (all available parameters included):

```
this.listenTo(yourCollection, 'request', function(collection, resp, options) {
  console.log('Request: ', resp);
});
this.listenTo(yourCollection, 'error', function(collection, resp, options) {
  console.log('Error: ', resp);
});
this.listenTo(yourCollection, 'sync', function(collection, resp, options) {
  console.log('Sync: ', resp);
});
```

So you should be able to just listen to the `error` event to display your custom error message:

```
this.listenTo(yourCollection, 'error', function(collection, resp) {
  if (resp.status === 401) {
    console.warn('401: Unauthorized');
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks.
I had tried this approach as well. After a couple of days scrambling over the code I found that the problem I was having had to do more with bootstrap than with backbone. I was trying to stop the rending of my view ( which was loaded in a modal ) if i got a 401. What I failed to notice over those 2 days was that the modal was fired independently by bootstrap and it had nothing to do with my render. Hence, me trying to catch the error in multiple ways and unable to stop the modal from opening... In any case, now i changed the logic so that the modal is open manually if i dont get a 401.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you will need to define some callback options for you addressBook fetch. For what you are trying to accomplish, you need to provide the error callback.

```
this.addressBook.fetch({
 error: function(xhr) {
   if(xhr.status == 401) { // Put logic you want in the case of 401 here... 
 }
});
```

Disclaimer: I have not tested this code, as I do not have a convenient way I can think of to reproduce this problem.

I believe it works because Backbone passes a jQuery xhr Object to its error callback. http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch